# How to find time stamp and decimal value reading from data stream in Java

Tags: java, arduino, inputstream

So if we pretend that we have the following data being streamed into Java from a microcontroller using Serial Port:

```
0x21 0x32 0xCC 0x00 0x3A 0x98 0x02 0x12 0x03 0x21 0x33 0x01 0xC2
```

I initially believed that the first byte was the Magic Number and the second byte was the Key. So wouldn't that make the numbers `0xCC 0x00 0x3A 0x98 0x02 0x12 0x03 0x21 0x33 0x01 0xC2` the value that we're reading from the microcontroller which we just combined all of the numbers in order to get the following reading in decimal value: `204058... and on`?

And for the time stamp don't we just convert the second byte which is `0x32` to decimal which is `50 unites of time`?

Comment: How about you read the documentation of the microcontroller? Then you'd know exactly what the data means.

Comment: How do you get from `0xCC 0x00 0x3A 0x98 0x02 0x12 0x03 0x21 0x33 0x01 0xC2` to `204058...`? Oh, you mean 0xCC=204, 0x00=0, 0x3A=58, ... and then you just string concatenate the base-10 stringified values of those bytes? Yeah, no, i very highly doubt that it works like that.

Comment: @Andreas on the documentation it mentioned that the payload was a key-value pair and 0x32 was for "timestamp, 4-byte integer, milliseconds since reset" and 0x33 "potentiometer reading, 2-byte integer A/D counts" so does that mean the next time I hit 0x32 which is the second number and since its a 4-byte integer we concatonate 0xCC and 0x00 0x3A and 0x98?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting comment:

> on the documentation it mentioned that the payload was a key-value pair and 0x32 was for "timestamp, 4-byte integer, milliseconds since reset" and 0x33 "potentiometer reading, 2-byte integer A/D counts" so does that mean the next time I hit 0x32 which is the second number and since its a 4-byte integer we concatonate 0xCC and 0x00 0x3A and 0x98?

Quoting example data from question:

> ```
> 0x21 0x32 0xCC 0x00 0x3A 0x98 0x02 0x12 0x03 0x21 0x33 0x01 0xC2
> ```

---

So, key/value pairs, where the key is a single byte, and each key has values of differing length.

> 0x32 was for "timestamp, 4-byte integer, milliseconds since reset"

```
0x21 0x32 0xCC 0x00 0x3A 0x98 0x02 0x12 0x03 0x21 0x33 0x01 0xC2
     ^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
     key    4-byte integer
```

Those 4 bytes can be big-endian or little-endian, but big-endian is more common for devices, so:

```
0xCC003A98 = 3422567064 ms = 39 days 14 hrs 42 mins 47.064 secs
```

---

> 0x33 "potentiometer reading, 2-byte integer A/D counts"

```
0x21 0x32 0xCC 0x00 0x3A 0x98 0x02 0x12 0x03 0x21 0x33 0x01 0xC2
                                                  ^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^
                                                  key  2-byte integer

0x01C2 = 450
```